# How to hide an image when side menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm no expert at coding so apologies if silly error -

I want the icon which opens the side menu to be hidden when the side menu is open and to be visible when the side menu is closed. This is the relevant snippets of my code so far but it's not working. Has it got something do do with scope or is my jquery wrong or something?

```js
// Open/close side menu
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '0';
}

// Show/hide side menu icon
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open-slide").show();

  if (openSlideMenu()) {
    $(".open-slide").hide();
  } else if (closeSlideMenu()) {
    $(".open-slide").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="side-menu" class="side-bar">
  <!-- Close Button -->
  <a href="#" id="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">&times;</a>
  <!-- Links -->
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Account</a>
  <a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>

<!-- Open sidebar icon -->
<div id="menu-icon">
  <span class="open-slide">
    <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
      <img src="./images/menu.svg" width="30" height="30">
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's simple. Just call `$(".open-slide").hide();` in the function `openSlideMenu` and the opposite. Also, why do you mixing vanila and jQuery? If you are using jQuery, take it all over..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show/Hide the icon with your functions instead of checking when the function is called:

```
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '250px';
  $(".open-slide").hide();
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '0';
  $(".open-slide").show();
}
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you! This does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as the answer you were looking for so other people can see what made your code work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function to show/hide your side menu is not correct. You can rather show/hide the menu in your `openSlideMenu()` and `closeSlideMenu()` functions.

Check the code for help:

```
 function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '250px';
  document.getElementByClassName('open-slide').style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }

 function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('heading-one').style.marginLeft = '0';
  document.getElementByClassName('open-slide').style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you can't put the function inside the if statement - what would be better is to check the elements you are altering.

For instance, if the .side-menu element is 250px, hide the image - otherwise show the image.